# MQ-4 Sensor working fine with Beetle Bluno BLE but not with Arduino Nano 33 BLE

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, voltage-level, arduino-nano-ble, bluno

I have an MQ-4 sensor connected to a Beetle Bluno BLE that seems to work fine, however, when I change the board to an Arduino Nano 33 BLE, the sensor doesn't seem to work well (I get an arbitrary oscillation in values coming from the sensor but these don't increase or decrease with the presence of gas).

**Beetle Bluno BLE setup:**

- MQ-4:GND -> Beetle:GND
- MQ-4:VCC -> Beetle:5v
- MQ-4:AO -> Beetle:A1

**Arduino Nano 33 BLE setup:**

- MQ-4:GND -> Arduino:GND
- MQ-4:VCC -> Arduino:3.3v
- MQ-4:AO -> Arduino:A1

[image]
(image slightly missleading because VCD is actually not connected to 5V but to 3.3V)

The only difference is the 5v instead of 3.3v, however, I also tried powering the sensor externally with 5v and it makes no difference.

Comment: A schematic might be helpful, particularly for the Arduino, along with "not working well" actually means.

Comment: Description updated with a schematic and a definition

Comment: You fixed the 5V jumper and verified it's putting out 5V?

Comment: No, I am not using the 5v but the 3.3v pin instead

Comment: AFAIK that sensor requires 5V according to sources like the [SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9404).

Comment: I see, well I tried powering the sensor with 5v externally with the same results

Comment: Which is why a schematic would be helpful to see if there's a missing shared ground or something.

Comment: I really don't know how to make schematics, but what I've done is connect the VCC and GND of the MQ-4 sensor to my other Beetle Bluno board to pins V5 and GND, and pin A0 stayed in Arduino Nano

Comment: I think the ground connection would also need to be hooked up to the Arduino if I'm understanding what you're saying.

Comment: After adding the ground to the Arduino, it seems like it is reading the values from the sensor, however, the values are "micro-oscillating" up and down in a way that doesn't happen in the Beetle Bluno

Comment: There are any number of reasons that could be happening; wiring and power supplies are often the first places to look when dealing with analog signals. (Which is not what I usually do, so I'm probably useless :)

Comment: Try hand drawing the schematic. There are a lot of videos on line that will explain it to you. Frizzing is not considered a schematic it leaves to many things unconnected. A hint when the supplier says 5V they do not expect it to work with much less or more, that is a very important parameter. Also it is a big help when you post links to the technical information on the hardware items. The next most important thing is current, can your power supply supply enough current. The Arduino a Power Supply it is NOT! Violating this rule can cause a lot of problems especially with analog hardware.